# Your scripts couldn’t add new variables to the environment. To add them, request Editor access on this environment

Tags: javascript, postman

when I am trying to set an environmental variable in postman , getting an error : Your scripts couldn’t add new variables to the environment. To add them, request Editor access on this environment.
One of colleague is also working on same workspace, but he doesn't get an error

when I am trying to set an environmental variable in postman , getting an error : Your scripts couldn’t add new variables to the environment. To add them, request Editor access on this environment.
One of colleague is also working on same workspace, he is not getting that error